# Is there a way to assign a ContextMenuStrip to a ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem, contextmenustrip

I want to assign the same ContextMenuStrip to all of the ListViewItems on a form. These ListViewItems are created dynamically.

Unfortunately, it seems ListViewItems do not have a ContextMenuStrip property that can be assigned to (of course, the ListView itself does).

Will I have to just assign the ContextMenuStrip to the ListView and then, based on the ListView's currently selected item, proceed from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hitTestInfo = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hitTestInfo.Item != null)
        {
            var loc = e.Location;
            loc.Offset(listView1.Location);

            // Adjust context menu (or it's contents) based on hitTestInfo details
            this.contextMenuStrip2.Show(this, loc);
        }
    }
}
```